# how to check if string has consecutive characters in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I'm trying to check if a string contains consecutive characters in vb.net

Example:

```
'test@01' - not ok
'test@02 - ok
'testab' - not ok
'testac' - ok
'testabc' not ok
```

string should not have any consecutive characters. (both numbers & alphabets) alphanumeric

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), A.K.A try something. Also C# != VB.net, please don't spam tags.

Comment: post your input string. And C# or vb.net?

Comment: Regex is not your best friend here, it will be very long.

Comment: is `"cba"` OK (consecutive, but in *descending* order)?

Comment: is `"aBc"` OK (consecutive in *case insensitive* comparison)

Comment: is `"Test@A"` is OK (technically, according ascii charmap `@` preceeds `A`)?

Comment: @George I have removed c# tag. that was by mistake. I need in vb.net

Comment: consecutive characters in ascending order... not in descending order... It is case-insesitive...

Comment: fine with ANSII... no need to handle @A.. i need alpha numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is very *vague* one. Let alone the language (C# or VB) there're many ambiguities:

- Is `"cba"` OK (conseq. but in *descending* order)?
- Is `"aBc"` OK (conseq. when *case* is ignored)?
- Is `"x@A"` OK (according ascii charater table `'@'` preceeds `'A'`)?

in case when the answers are all *No*'s (*ascending* order only, case *sensitive*, *both* characters must be letters and digits only), a simple loop solves the task (C#):

```
  string source = "test@01";
  bool result = false;

  for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; ++i)
    if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(source[i]) && char.IsLetterOrDigit(source[i - 1]))
      if (source[i] - source[i - 1] == 1) { 
        result = true;

        break;
      }
```

...

```
Console.Write(result ? "OK" : "Not OK");
```

**Edit:** if you want *case insensitive* test you have to compare

```
 if (char.ToUpperInvariant(source[i]) - char.ToUpperInvariant(source[i - 1]) == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. give me few minutes. I will try this and let you know

Comment: thank you for edit!! it worked. Thanks alot you made my day. Worked in all scenerios.